# Athena catalog query very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbt

I have a dbt data pipeline which creates lots of athena tables with lots of files, and I noticed that the all of the runs are taking long to run even simple queries... so in dbt.log I found this query:

```
WITH views AS (
      select
        table_catalog as database,
        table_name as name,
        table_schema as schema
      from "awsdatacatalog".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views
      where table_schema = LOWER('graphs_db')
    ), tables AS (
      select
        table_catalog as database,
        table_name as name,
        table_schema as schema

      from "awsdatacatalog".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
      where table_schema = LOWER('graphs_db')

      -- Views appear in both `tables` and `views`, so excluding them from tables
      EXCEPT 

      select * from views
    )
    select views.*, 'view' AS table_type FROM views
    UNION ALL
    select tables.*, 'table' AS table_type FROM tables
```

It probably runs before anything to check what tables it can use.
Anyways this query is taking 5 minutes to run. I have several dbt steps in my pipeline so this is significantly slowing it down. Is it normal? Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: What do your partitions look like?

Comment: actually we don't use partitioning(only bucketing) at all yet, but we create dozens of tables per client project which effectively serves as our partitions, I think the issue is that we're creating too many tables with too many files... in the input we write the files first so that athena can create the tables from them (before running the dbt pipeline). So I think we need to revise the batching strategy for creating those files.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look into this [Tips to improve the Athena Query Performance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/)

specially point no **4**.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is kind of implicit but it seems like because I have too many files (and I am aware of that issue so it definitely resonates), then the catalog takes too long to load because in order for a table to be listed in the catalog, athena has to check which files are available for each table or something like that, and that is what slows down the query, am I correct? In this case the solution would be to concatenate some of those files together to reduce this file scan time

Comment: If you have so many small files, that is one reason to slow down your query.